# Fitting a curve "around" data points in R

Tags: r, optimization

i have a data set consisting of a collection of points. the points are distributed on the plane in such a way that they can be roughly bounded by a parabola. i am trying to find a way of fitting a parabola to the boundary of the points.

this is what i have at present:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

parabola <- function(x) {
    a * x^2 + b * x + c
}

N = 10000

x <- runif(N, -4, 3)
y <- runif(N, 0, 10)

data <- data.frame(x, y)

data <- subset(data, y >= parabola(x))

plot(data, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 10), col = "grey")

fr <- function(x) {
    PAR = x[1] * data$x^2 + x[2] * data$x + x[3]
    #
    sum((PAR - data$y)^2 + 100 * plogis(PAR - data$y, scale = 0.00001))
}

par = optim(c(0, 0, 0), fr)$par

a = par[1]
b = par[2]
c = par[3]

curve(parabola, add = TRUE, lty = "dashed")
```

this creates a sample data set and then fits a curve to the boundary. the objective function consists of a "normal" squared error term, which fits a parabola to the data as well as a second logistic term which penalizes points which live below the parabola. the parameters (100 and 0.00001) of this second term were determined by trial and error.

the code plots the points as well as the fitted parabola.

now this system works... but only some of the time. sometimes it produces a fit that is completely wrong and i guess that in these instances the parameters for the logistic term are just inappropriate. run the code a few times to see what i mean.

i am sure that there must be a more robust way of solving this problem. ideas and suggestions?

.

Comment: The default algorithm in `optim` isn't very good. Try specifying `method="BFGS"` or `method="L-BFGS-B"`.

Comment: Set the random number seed to get a reproducible example of your problem. If I do `set.seed(999)` and run your code, is that an example of a wrong fit? Gives us something to work with! In this case, `method="BFGS"` produces a much better fit...

Comment: yes, precisely: with a seed of 999 it fails but with a seed of 1 it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not provide a complete answer. The only ad hoc idea I had was to provide better starting points for the optimization algorithm - hoping you are closer to the local minimum of the function you try to optimize.

Estimating a rough first version is fairly simple. If you write your parabola as `b*(x-a)^2+c`
you can estimate

```
a <- data$x[which.min(data$y)]
c <- min(data$y)
 
b1 <- (data$y[which.min(data$x)] - c) / (min(data$x) - a)^2
b2 <- (data$y[which.max(data$x)] - c) / (max(data$x) - a)^2
b <- mean(c(b1, b2))
```

---

### EDIT

I had another intensive testing session with my suggestion and the method "BFGS". I could not find a counter example with the following approach:

```
seed <- floor(runif(1,1,1000))
set.seed(seed)
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

parabola <- function(x) {
    b * (x-a)^2 + c
}

N = 10000

x <- runif(N, -4, 3)
y <- runif(N, 0, 10)

data <- data.frame(x, y)

data <- subset(data, y >= parabola(x))

plot(data, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 10), col = "grey")

fr <- function(x) {
    PAR = x[2] * (data$x - x[1])^2 + x[3]
    #
    sum((PAR - data$y)^2 + 100 * plogis(PAR - data$y, scale = 0.00001))
}

a <- data$x[which.min(data$y)]
c <- min(data$y)

b1 <- (data$y[which.min(data$x)] - c) / (min(data$x) - a)^2
b2 <- (data$y[which.max(data$x)] - c) / (max(data$x) - a)^2
b <- mean(c(b1, b2))

par = optim(c(a, b, c), fr, method="BFGS")$par

a = par[1]
b = par[2]
c = par[3]

curve(parabola, add = TRUE, lty = "dashed")
```

However, correct convergence is not guaranteed. I tried about 50 cases and all went well. Is your result reviewed or does it have to work correctly on an automated basis?

---

### EDIT 2

I had a few thoughts on how you could update your objective function to be more reliable. Right now I do not have the time to work out a complete solution, but maybe this thoughts may help you:

We have date within `range(data$x)`. Now we want to find a parabola that fits the lower boundary of this data as good as possible - or, in other words, find values a,b,c that maximize

```
\int_{\range(x)} ax^2 + bx+c dx
```

(Please excuse the clumsy LaTeX - writing formulas sometimes just is better).

Now, penalizing points below the parabola could be done using a penalty function like

```
\lambda (ax_i^2+bx_i+c - y_i)^2 if below parabola, 0 otherwise
```

Subtracting that function from the interval should give you a suitable, smooth objective function. Simplifying the function as good a possible seems to be a better model than using the least squares approach, which tries to fit a line through the *middle* of the datapoints.

You will still have to chosse a suitable lambda, though. But that is typical: You need a compromise between two different objectives (fitting data, maximizing the parabola). The weight which one is more important has to be submitted by you.

Comment: thanks, thilo, yes, that does work very robustly. the idea of starting with decent values for the parameters makes complete sense!

Comment: my only remaining issue is the fact that the objective function feels a little ad-hoc. i know that it works, but i would like to believe that there must be a better solution that does not rely on the arbitrary tuning parameters 100 and 0.00001.

Comment: another small snag: if you reduce the number of points being fitted then the performance drops off appreciably. setting N = 100 and seeding with 969 will illustrate this effect: a number of points now fall outside the parabola. i think that the issue comes down to how to make the penalty for points outside the parabola quite severe, yet not so severe that it completely swamps the squared error term.

Comment: and, finally, no, the solution needs to work on a automated basis.

Comment: I feared something like that - automated algorithms usually are much harder to develop, as you may always hit some boundary case you have not thought of... I will edit my answer with a thought I just had during breakfast ;)

Answer (score 0):

further thanks to thilo for his very helpful suggestions and correcting my naive ideas. based on thilo's suggestion, using the area under the parabola and suitable penalty function, the solution below seems to work. i also changed to L-BFGS-B optimisation because it performed better with small N.

```
parabola.objective <- function(p) {
    d = p[2] * (data$x - p[1])^2 + p[3] - data$y
    #
    area <- function(x) {
        p[2] / 3 * (x - p[1])^3 + p[3] * x
    }
    #
    sum(- area(max(data$x)) + area(min(data$x)) + 100 * ifelse(d > 0, d^2, 0))
}

A <- data$x[which.min(data$y)]
C <- min(data$y)

B1 <- (data$y[which.min(data$x)] - C) / (min(data$x) - A)^2
B2 <- (data$y[which.max(data$x)] - C) / (max(data$x) - A)^2
B <- mean(c(B1, B2))

# the key to getting this working with a small number of points is the
# optimisation method: BFGS works well with around 300 points or more
# but L-BFGS-B seems to perform better down to around 100 points.
#
O = optim(c(A, B, C), parabola.objective, method="L-BFGS-B")

par = O$par

A = par[1]
B = par[2]
C = par[3]

curve(parabola, add = TRUE, lty = "dashed")
```

Comment: I have to confess that I am a bit surprised. With your optimization method, a parabola that fits much more than the given points should yield the same objective function value. The only reason I can imagine is that the starting values usually fit a parabola that is "to small" and that optimization happens to hit a function close to the best fit. I still would suggest adding some penalty term for to big parabolas (even if it is just `+p[3] + c*p[2]`, which could be enough)

Comment: hi thilo, you are quite right. this did work for all of the nice, neat "test" cases that were being generated by my sample code. but when i took it out into the real world it broke horribly. very naive of me to think that this would work. if the initial parabola starts out amongst the data points then this objective function seems to produce reasonable results. otherwise it fails miserably. so your surprise is completely warranted and i am humbled.